# Sometimes text_field and css scroll don't work on mobile device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

Ruby : 2.3.1
Rails: 5.2.2

I make a responsive web application and have encountered unacceptable bugs.
I searched for various things, but I couldn't find a person who encountered the same bug.

▪️Detail
The following bugs sometimes occur when using an application:
Sometimes, It doesn't focus into the field even if I tap text_field, email_field and text_area.
"a tag on html" still works. It seems tap function is not wrong.

1. Visit to form page.
2. Tap text_field, email_field and text_area.
3. Sometimes, it doesn't focus.

Sometimes the bug is fixed after having left time or visiting another page although I'm not sure.

▪️Inspect
I checked the above bugs below:
・mobile phone emulator(device toolbar of chrome devtools)
・ios(12.1.2)
・Android(8.0.0)

Also, when the bug appears, scroll doesn't work only on the actual mobile device, both of ios and Android.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my self.

▪ cause
There was a page handling JS touch event, but because the scrolling function wasn't added in that event.

There was a bug that scroll couldn't be done on the above page.
When transitioned to another page that has text_field via scroll bug page, it seemed that scroll bug remained because of turbolinks.
And text_field didn't work.

I found that text_field bug was fixed by followings:

- when reloaded the page.
- when transitioned to the page via a tag with data-turbolinks =
  "false".

At first I fixed scroll bug on touch event page.
And then text_field bug was also fixed.

> Also, when the above bug comes out, there is a bug in which scroll
>   does not work only on the actual machine of mobile. There is no
>   problem with the emulator.

This was completely my misunderstanding, even the bug occurred in the emulator too.